# Filtering data from result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

how I can filter data after every request? Should I use IActionFilter or IResultFilter? If one request returns a string, another a list of specifics object, how I can know to the right type inside a filter and then "remove" data from the result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cab ou dd some code samples and specify better ?

Answer (score 0):

`IActionFilter` is more about some shared logic, like logging, adding some headers or transformations that are applicable for at least several controllers.

If it is not your case, I would suggest creating additional service per controller and do filtering there. This will give you flexibility and allows test your filtering.

Answer (score 0):

ActionFilter would enough for this requirement. For example, OData uses EnableQuery attribute. If you use that way, you can check the data type with reflection.

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/d02bc61ea7b31ada1e54abbeebbecb3c5df0e3ac/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs

You can refer the code above.

Good luck,
Alim